# How can I add a header value to response using unfiltered netty, how write code?

Tags: scala, netty, response.addheader, unfiltered

I response a stream, and I want add headerName `fileName` to response's header. But I don't wirte?

```
req.respond(CharContentType("text/csv") ~> ResponseBytes(xxxxx.usersExport))
```

I know a `Header.scala` https://github.com/unfiltered/unfiltered/blob/master/library/src/main/scala/response/headers.scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by myself:

```
req.respond(new ResponseHeader("key","value") ~> CharContentType("text/csv") ~> ResponseBytes(xxxxx.usersExport))
```

Answer (score 4):

In current version of unfiltered just respond with following code:

```
Ok ~> ResponseHeader("Content-Type", Set("application/json"))
```